# Simple input and output in assembly x86_64

Tags: linux, assembly, x86

I am new assembly programming in Linux (x86_64) and I want to make sure that I am programing in a correct way. I wrote a program that just takes an input from the user and then writes his input to stdout

```
SYS_WRITE   equ 1 ; write text to stdout
SYS_READ    equ 0 ; read text from stdin
SYS_EXIT    equ 60 ; terminate the program
STDOUT      equ 1 ; stdout

section .bss
    uinput resb 24 ; 24 bytes for user string
    uinput_len equ $ - uinput ; get length of user input

section .data
    text db "You wroted: "
    text_len equ $ - text

section .text
    global _start

_start:
    mov rax, SYS_READ
    mov rdi, STDOUT
    mov rsi, uinput
    mov rdx, uinput_len
    syscall

    mov rax, SYS_WRITE
    mov rdi, STDOUT
    mov rsi, text
    mov rdx, text_len
    syscall

    mov rax, SYS_WRITE
    mov rdi, STDOUT
    mov rsi, uinput
    mov rdx, uinput_len
    syscall

    mov rax, SYS_EXIT
    mov rsi, 0 ; successful exit
    syscall
```

Am I doing this experiment correctly?
Which suggestions do you find to improve this code?
Could you please provide some resources to deepen in good practices (and if posible more features or effective techniques)?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Three small errors

> ```
> section .data
>    text db "You wroted: "
>    text_len equ $ - text
> ```

A small spelling error (typo). Correct is: "You wrote: " without the **d**.

---

> ```
> mov rax, SYS_READ
> mov rdi, STDOUT
> mov rsi, uinput
> mov rdx, uinput_len
> syscall
> ```

For *SYS_READ* you need to use *STDIN* instead of *STDOUT*.

---

> ```
> mov rax, SYS_EXIT
> mov rsi, 0 ; successful exit
> syscall
> ```

The first parameter goes in the `RDI` register instead of `RSI`.

#### Three small improvements

> ```
> section .bss
>    uinput resb 24 ; 24 bytes for user string
>    uinput_len equ $ - uinput ; get length of user input
> ```

It's strange to see a calculation for the *uinput_len* variable given that the length is a hardcoded 24. What you can write is:

```
section .bss
    uinput_len equ     24         ; 24 bytes for user input
    uinput     resb    uinput_len
```

---

Be nice for the person that uses your program and show a prompt of some kind before expecting an input.

---

For the final result you currently show the whole inputbuffer. What if the user didn't input that much characters? Best to only show the characters that were effectively inputted. You obtain this count in the `RAX` register upon returning from *SYS_READ*. e.g. If the user inputs 5 characters then `RAX` will hold 6. Those 5 characters plus the terminating newline character (0Ah).

#### Same code, different style

You should offset you tail comments so that they all start in the same column. This will improve readability.
And because **readability is very very important**, I've applied the same rule to the labels, mnemonics, and operands.

```
    SYS_READ   equ     0          ; read text from stdin
    SYS_WRITE  equ     1          ; write text to stdout
    SYS_EXIT   equ     60         ; terminate the program
    STDIN      equ     0          ; standard input
    STDOUT     equ     1          ; standard output
; --------------------------------
section .bss
    uinput_len equ     24         ; 24 bytes for user input
    uinput     resb    uinput_len ; buffer for user input
; --------------------------------
section .data
    prompt     db      "Please input some text: "
    prompt_len equ     $ - prompt
    text       db      10, "You wrote: "
    text_len   equ     $ - text
; --------------------------------
section .text
    global _start

_start:
    mov     rdx, prompt_len
    mov     rsi, prompt
    mov     rdi, STDOUT
    mov     rax, SYS_WRITE
    syscall

    mov     rdx, uinput_len
    mov     rsi, uinput
    mov     rdi, STDIN
    mov     rax, SYS_READ
    syscall                      ; -> RAX
    push    rax                  ; (1)

    mov     rdx, text_len
    mov     rsi, text
    mov     rdi, STDOUT
    mov     rax, SYS_WRITE
    syscall

    pop     rdx                  ; (1)
    mov     rsi, uinput
    mov     rdi, STDOUT
    mov     rax, SYS_WRITE
    syscall

    xor     edi, edi             ; successful exit
    mov     rax, SYS_EXIT
    syscall
```

Instead of `mov rdi, 0`, I've used `xor edi, edi` which is shorter and faster and leaves the same result (0) in the `RDI` register.

I always prefer to write the function number directly above the `syscall` instruction. I find this clearer. As a consequence I've also inversed the order of the other parameters, again for clarity.

---

---

You can learn a lot about 64-bit Linux programming from the .PDF that you can [download here](http://www.egr.unlv.edu/%7Eed/assembly64.pdf)
It provides good examples that deal with console input and console output and more.